# How to use WeirdX applet instead of X11 for remote connections in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, xorg, x11-forwarding

1. When I am away, I've got an Apple PowerBook set up to use X11 forwarding with SSH to connect to a remote iMac in my room.
2. Whenever I start X client programs on the client iMac, X11 would start on my PowerBook, which is OK.
3. Question: Is it possible to change my settings so that the [WeirdX](http://www.jcraft.com/weirdx/) applet I have on my PowerBook will take care of the X client programs instead of the default X11? Is there a config file I can edit to chance the $DISPLAY variable, and what should I set it to? Is this even the issue?

Thank you very much.